# Highlighting the img tag by setting background image with larger size

Tags: css, background-image, highlight, image-resizing

I have two images one is textbox.png of size  16X16px and the other one is IconBG.png  with 24X24 pixel.
I am defining a img tag as

```
<img id="g_TextButton"  src="../icons/textbox.png" alt="Text" title="Text" onclick="javascript:void(selectTool(this, 5))">
```

On click of this ,I am setting the background img for the img tag as below-

```
function selectTool(objThis) {
    //----some code
    objThis.style.backgroundImage="url('../icons/IconBG.png')";


}
```

But as the img tag size is not predefined ,it will occupy 16px initially .After selection when I set the background image of 24 px, the size is still 16px .I cannot initialize the img tag size as 24px bz,with this even the 16px icon is reset to 24px.

So my requirement is have a place holder with size 24X24.And initially place a img of 16X16 in it. Onclick add the background image of 24X24px.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can achieve this easily with css only :

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="../icons/textbox.png" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: relative;
}

#container:hover {
    background-image: url('../icons/IconBG.png');
}

#container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And the good thing is, the :hover will load the second img (img24px) onload and not on first call like it would happen by default in JS.

Comment: This works absolutely fine.But how can we set the background-image: url('../icons/IconBG.png'); inline onselect of the img???

Comment: Now it is happening on hover.But it should be retained untill it is set back to null or empty background

Comment: objThis.parentNode.style.backgroundImage="url('../icons/IconBG.png')";  With is onselect I am able to highlight till I remove the background image.Thanks you very much.:-):-)